# Jquery UI date picker to format the date

Tags: jquery

I'm using date picker. I'm trying to change the format of date but I got following error.

`Unable to parse date specified in strtotime()`

Here is what I have tried:

```
  $(function()
  {  
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
      { 
       var x = dateText;
       var y= x.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2000-11-02');
       var z= $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      } 
     });
   }
```

I want the date in yy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        {dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
                var theDate = new Date(Date.parse($(this).datepicker('getDate')));
                var dateFormatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', theDate);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: :It is not outputting in this format: 2011-12-23.I want it in that format

Comment: see edited code, it should produce 2011-12-23 format date... hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'y-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datepicker format of yours:

html:

```
<input name="date" class="datepicker" type="text" />
```

javascript:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

after the submit you can convert the date field to mysql datetime format with php.

php:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $POST['date'])));
```

modify the above lines to your desired ones.

Comment: :post variable is receiving the correct date but my o/p is like this 31-12-69.